# Set firebase functions region in javascript app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I set the region in my **Web** Firebase app? I've deployed functions to `us-east4` but they are always called pointed to `us-central1`?

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/functions";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).functions('us-east4'); // tried it here
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myFunction')({});
```

Unfortunately, the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initializeapp) only tell me initialization options are `Object` so I don't know what can be used there.

--

```
var functions = firebase.functions("us-east4");
```

> Argument of type '"us-east4"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'App | undefined'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to reference the firebase app, not the global `firebase` import, using `firebase.app().functions(region)`

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/functions";
firebase.initializeApp({...})
const functions = firebase.app().functions('us-east4');
const response = await functions.httpsCallable('myFunction');
```